# "_Problem loading widget" in release version only

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I've a really weird behavior with the App widget:
I've a home screen widget with a ListView showing data from internet.

It's working fine with no problem at all on the `debug version`, 
but when I `install release`:
when I drag the widget to the home screen it shows **"problem loading widget"** and in the Logcat:

```
E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.askelp.askelp-u7QWKA4gT6KmeGou17fWHw==/base.apk  
E/RemoteViews: Package name com.askelp.askelp not found
```

BUT if I left it in the home screen and reinstalled the app it works then, and if I removed the widget from the home screen and reinstalled it again and dragged it again to the home screen it shows the same error and **"problem loading widget"**

Anyone has any idea?

**EDIT:**

I tried now to run it on my phone it's working, so it's working on my phone but not working in the emulator!

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: Any update? still happening here.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution1 :**

Have you try to `invalidate cache/restart?`

**Solution 2:**

From the [Documentation Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#CreatingLayout) , You can only use this as widgets

A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:

*FrameLayout

*LinearLayout

*RelativeLayout

*GridLayout

And the following widget classes:

*AnalogClock

*Button

*Chronometer

*ImageButton

*ImageView

*ProgressBar

*TextView

*ViewFlipper

*ListView

*GridView

*StackView

*AdapterViewFlipper

Comment: How can invalidate cache?

Comment: go to `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart  > click Invalidate and Restart`

and wait for it to reload

Comment: may I see the logcat?@YousefGamal

Comment: The logcat is the same as in the question:
E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.askelp.askelp-u7QWKA4gT6KmeGou17fWHw==/base.apk  
E/RemoteViews: Package name com.askelp.askelp not found